# Generating access code

Tags: php, access-token

I want to generate access code to the website I am making, and make it accessible only by that token. Now, I want the token to have particular information - email address, time +24hrs. I want to perform a cron job every hour to check whether those 24 hours have been reached and delete the token if it has.

I thought of using hash codes, but how can I retrieve information from a hash code? Is there such a function in php to decode a hash code? Because I couldn't find it...

If there isn't, what could be an alternative algorithm for generating access codes?

EDIT: I will use base64_encode(). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the information in the token. Store the information in a database. The token should be randomly generated (and used as the key value).

(Hashes are designed to be one-way, you shouldn't be able to decode them).

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for. I am going to use base64_encode()

Comment: @LukasBijaminas — Don't use base64_encode, it is a completely unnecessary leak of data. Use a random token.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reverse the process of hashing. The best you can do is a brute-force it which is hardly reliable.

You should create a hashed string and store it along with other info in a database. Then in your cron script, check against the database.